# Negative part of a function

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Hello i have a functional $I:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$I(u)=\int_{\Omega} \varphi(|u(x)|) u(x) v(x) dx $$

and we define $u^-=\min\{0,u\}$

does we have  $$I(u)=-\int_{\Omega} \varphi(|u^-(x)|)u^-(x) v(x) dx$$ or not ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tricky to give a precise answer as you haven't specified what $X$ or $\varphi$ are, but I still doubt that this identity is true.  Consider a function $u \ge 0$ on $\Omega$.  Then $u^- =0$, and so
$$
\int_{\Omega} \varphi(|u^-|) u^- v =0
$$
whereas
$$
\int_\Omega \varphi(|u|) u v = \int_\Omega \varphi(u) u v.
$$
If there exists a single nonnegative $u$ for which the latter integral doesn't vanish, then you have a contradiction.